# Finding a symbolic link when you don't know what directory it is in?

Tags: bash, terminal, sublimetext, symlink

I created a symbolic link to open files with sublime 2 from terminal using

```
subl file.txt
```

I have now upgraded to sublime 3 and am looking to change that link to point to the new version of sublime.

I cant seem to find that link anywhere though. Is there a way to show the file location using only the symbolic link?

Comment: If you know where the link is, you can simply use `ls -l subl` to show what it links to.

Comment: I don't know where the original link is. I have checked usr/bin as well as the bash profiles but I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `which subl` to show where the system thinks `subl` is.

Comment: That was it! I can't believe it was so simple. I've been trying to use find and grep when all I needed was which. Thank you!

Comment: Alternatively, `type -a subl`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, use `which` to find out what the `sub1` points at (unless this part is already know to you). Then use `find / -lname <full path you got on previous command>`. In one line on bash you can do `find / -lname $(which sub1)`.

Comment: Also noteworthy (but may be less portable): `readlink -f symlink`